# how to install gitlab-runner on Debian 11 using package manager

Tags: debian, apt, debian-packaging, gitlab-runner

I was trying to install GitLab-runner using apt package manager.

`curl -L "https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/runner/gitlab-runner/script.deb.sh" | sudo bash`

but there is no GitLab runner package for debian11 right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for now there is no GitLab-runner package on Debian 11 so you should use Debian 10 packages to install from package manager:

1. `curl -L "https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/runner/gitlab-runner/script.deb.sh" | sudo bash`
2. `sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/runner_gitlab-runner.list`
3. replace content of this file with this `deb https://packages.gitlab.com/runner/gitlab-runner/debian/ buster main deb-src https://packages.gitlab.com/runner/gitlab-runner/debian/ buster main`
4. `sudo apt update`
5. `sudo apt install gitlab-runner`

Comment: You need to set the pin priority https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-repository.html#apt-pinning

Answer (score 0):

This processes are old
just follow the gitlab orders:

```
# Download the binary for your system
sudo curl -L --output /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner https://gitlab-runner-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/binaries/gitlab-runner-linux-amd64

# Give it permission to execute
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner

# Create a GitLab Runner user
sudo useradd --comment 'GitLab Runner' --create-home gitlab-runner --shell /bin/bash

# Install and run as a service
sudo gitlab-runner install --user=gitlab-runner --working-directory=/home/gitlab-runner
sudo gitlab-runner start
```